# Listening on every input field in forms using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm working on a SPA that uses jQuery and one of the requirements is that I should trigger actions for particular values of input fields (checkboxes, dropdowns, text). I want to know from a performance perspective which of the following is faster or less cumbersome

```
$('input, select').on('click focus change', function(e){
//do something
});
```

or

```
$('form').on('click focus change', 'input, select', function(e){
//do something
});
```

Also, given that there will be asynchronous operations on the page, the second option is what I'm leaning towards but I wanted to check with you experts :)

Comment: The first will have slightly less overhead but it shouldn't matter much.  The benefit of the second is that it would work with dynamically created fields, not just the ones that are on the page when it loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second snippet attaches the event to the entire form.  If a user clicks/focuses/changes anything anywhere (especially the click) then the event fires.  As soon as it fires it then checks to see if it was done on an input or select and if not it aborts.  As a result, the second version has slightly higher overhead because it will sometimes fire for non input/select events.

The major benefit to the second format is for dynamically created elements.  Lets say that something the user does causes an additional field to be created on the form.  If that field was not on the page when the page initially loaded then the first version of your event will not fire when that field is changed/clicked.  But, the second version *would* fire.

My recommendation:  Unless you are specifically doing something with dynamic fields as I described, then I would use the first.  Honestly though, there is such a tiny difference that either would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance there isn't much to write home about. The difference (if any) is negligible. For asynchronous operations, i'd suggest you go for the 2nd snippet.